# Switching camera input session interrupts output

Tags: swift, video, camera, avfoundation

I'm trying to have a smooth transition from one camera to another, while recording video. I know this is notoriously hard to do but it really should be possible given many apps do it.

The best I've been able to do is by having two sessions running simultaneously, for the front and back, and switching which one outputs to the given AVCaptureMovieFileOutput (and changing the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer displayed).

Here's my code:

**Properties:**

```
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var backCameraActive = false
var isFrontRecording = false
var videoInputBack: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
var sessionBack: AVCaptureSession?
var isBackRecording = false
var videoInputFront: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
var sessionFront: AVCaptureSession?
private let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
```

**Set up sessions:**

```
sessionBack = AVCaptureSession()
sessionBack!.sessionPreset = .high
sessionBack!.startRunning()
let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back) ??
    AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)    
if let backCamera = backCamera {
    do {
        print("Back camera initialized")
        videoInputBack = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
        sessionBack!.addInput(videoInputBack!)
    } catch {
        print("Error initializing session for back input!")
    }
}
// Set up front camera
sessionFront = AVCaptureSession()
sessionFront!.sessionPreset = .high
sessionFront!.startRunning()
let frontCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .front) ??
    AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)      
if let frontCamera = frontCamera {
    do {
        print("Front camera initialized")
        videoInputFront = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)
        sessionFront!.addInput(videoInputFront!)
    } catch {
        print("Error initializing session for back input!")
    }
}
if let sessionBack = sessionBack {
    // Set up preview layer and output  
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: sessionBack)
    view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, at: 0)
    sessionBack.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
    backCameraActive = true
}
```

**Did tap record:**

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL
let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("tempMovie.mp4")
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.absoluteString) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePath)
    }
    catch {
        // exception while deleting old cached file
        // ignore error if any
    }
}
movieFileOutput.startRecording(to: filePath, recordingDelegate: self)
```

**Did Double Tap / Switch cameras:**

```
let fromSession = backCameraActive ? sessionBack! : sessionFront!
let toSession = backCameraActive ? sessionFront! : sessionBack!
backCameraActive = !backCameraActive
print("Front session: \(sessionFront!)")
print("Back session: \(sessionFront!)")
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.enter()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    fromSession.beginConfiguration()
    fromSession.removeOutput(self.movieFileOutput)
    fromSession.commitConfiguration()
    toSession.beginConfiguration()
    if toSession.canAddOutput(self.movieFileOutput) {
        toSession.addOutput(self.movieFileOutput)
        print("Output changed")
    }
    toSession.commitConfiguration()
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, work: DispatchWorkItem(block: {
    let newPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: toSession)
    newPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    newPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(newPreviewLayer, at: 0)
    self.previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    self.previewLayer = newPreviewLayer
}))
```

The switching of cameras actually automatically triggers the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` function `fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo ...)`, which brings up my preview ViewController. My intention is for the video to continue recording, and I can't find a way to customize the output so that it's possible.

I am thinking of switching the output from the current type to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, and using the separate audio and video tracks to make this run smoothly, but I'm not willing to risk more wasted time on this simple functionality at the moment.

Comment: Why do you use two different sessions? Normally for switching cameras you just have to change the session's input and leave the rest as-is.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Because that process is too slow, and switch cameras without interrupting input is impossible. At least it's what I've found people to say - but the interruption still happens.

Comment: Yes, correct. Re-configuring the session takes time since buffers need to be re-allocated, etc. You could use a `AVCaptureMultiCamSession` to always get the signal from both cameras, but only use one signal at a time to write to your output file, I guess.